# If phi is an isomorphism of $(S,*)$ with $(S',*')$ then prove $\phi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism of $(S',*')$ with $(S,*)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $\phi:S\to S'$ is an isomorphism of $(S,*)$ with $(S',*'),$ then

$\phi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism of $(S',*')$ with $(S,*)$

aside:

if $\phi$ is an isomorphism, then we know it is one-to-one, onto and homomorphic.

So, now we know $\phi^{-1}$ exists because it is one-to-one. Further, because $\phi$ is onto, we know that $\forall s' \in S'$ and $\ s \in S$ that $\phi(s)=s'.$
And, $\phi$ is homomorphic, so we know $\phi(s_1*s_2)=\phi(s_1)*'\phi(s_2)$

Proof (rough draft):

**(i)** $\phi(s_1) = \phi(s_2) \implies s_1 = s_2$ and so $\phi^{-1}(s_1') = \phi^{-1}(s_2') \implies s_1'=s_2'$ we have one-to-one

**(ii)** $\forall s' \in S'$ and $\forall s \in S,\space\phi(s)=s',$ thus $\phi^{-1}(s')= s,$ so we have onto

**(iii)** Because we have one-to-one giving us the inverse and it is onto, we have
$\phi(s_1*s_2)=\phi(s_1)*'\phi(s_2)$ $\implies$ $\phi^{-1}(s_1'*'s_2')=\phi^{-1}(s_1') * \phi^{-1}(s_2')$ thus homomorphic

This looks pretty hideous even to me, advice on cleaning it up.

Comment: "rough draft" = all details? lol

Comment: An alternative definition of *isomorphism* is: $\phi\colon X\to Y$ is an isomorphism if it is a morphism and there exists a morphism $\psi\colon Y\to X$ such that $\psi\circ\phi=\operatorname{id}_X$ and $\phi\circ\psi=\operatorname{id}_Y$. With this definition, the proof would be quite trivial - by the very symmetry of the definition itself.

Comment: yeah rough draft, being that it may need to be cleaned up. That definition is nice, I think my professor is looking for more than just that at the present time though.

Comment: would it be better this way

let $s \in S, s' \in S'$  and $\phi^{-1}(\phi(s))=s$

(i) $ \phi^{-1}(s_1') = \phi^{-1}(s_2') \implies s_1'=s_2'$ because $\phi$ is one-to-one

(ii) $ \phi^{-1}(s') = s$ because $\phi$ is onto

(iii) $ \phi^{-1}(s_1' *' s_2') = \phi^{-1}(s_1') * \phi^{-1}(s_2')$ because $\phi$ is homomorphic, one-to-one and onto

Comment: @oliverjones: you don't need to show that $\phi^{-1}$ one-one or onto. it follows from the definition of bijection between two sets. use the definition *Hagen von Eitzen* gave for sets (not for groups). then it just remains to show that it's a group homomorphism.

Comment: @krish so show $\phi \circ \phi^{-1}$ gives $S$ and then reverse to show it gives $S'$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two non-empty set and let $f: X \to Y$ be function. Then $f$ is a bijection if and only if there exists a function $g: Y \to X$ such that $fg = 1_Y$ and $gf = 1_X.$ This $g$ is denoted by $f^{-1}.$

Using the above, $\phi^{-1}$ is a bijection between $G$ and $G'.$ The only thing that needs to check is that it a group homomorphism.

Comment: It's not expressed that it is a group, so does that matter?

Comment: @oliverjones: No. it won't matter. look at the definition you gave of an isomorphism: it's one-one, onto and group homomorphism. that "one-one and onto" is just as a set. in otherwords, a group homomorphism is an isomorphism if it is a set theoretic bijection.

Comment: $\forall s \in S, s' \in S'$ $\phi(s_1 * s_2) = s_1' *' s_2' \implies \phi^{-1}(s_1' *' s_2') = s_1 * s_2 = \phi^{-1}(s_1') * \phi^{-1}(s_2')$

Comment: @oliverjones: yes!! you got it. :)

Comment: Polished version:

Proof:

Let $\phi$ be an isomorphism of $(S,*)$ with $(S',*')$ thus by definition $\phi$ is a bijection thus giving us an inverse mapping $\phi^{-1}: (S',*') \to (S,*)$

Now, $\forall s \in S, s' \in S',$ $\phi(s) = s' \Longleftrightarrow \phi^{-1}(s') =s$ 

 furthermore, $\phi(s_1 * s_2) = s_1' *' s_2' = \phi(s_1) *' \phi(s_2)$ implies that  $\phi^{-1}(s_1' *' s_2') = s_1 * s_2 = \phi^{-1}(s_1') * \phi^{-1}(s_2')$

thus $\phi^{-1}$ is a homomorphism and a bijection therefore $\phi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism of $(S',*')$ with $(S,*)$

Comment: @oliverjones: yep!! it's really nice. :)